# Limits of cosinus and sixth root

Tags: limits

I have two exercises and I don't know how to solve them

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x - \cos 3x}{x} $$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[6]{1+x+x^2} - 1}{x} $$

For the second one I know that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^r-1}{x} = r $$

Comment: What do you know about limits? Do you know l'Hopital rule?

Comment: Hint: Rewrite the fraction of the first limit to $$\frac{\cos x -1 }{x-0}- 3\cdot\frac{\cos 3x -1}{3x-0}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x- \cos 3x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x -1 }{x-0}- 3\cdot\frac{\cos 3x -1}{3x-0}= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos x \Big|_{x=0}+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos 3x \Big|_{x=0}=0+0.$$
The second limit can be solved in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

First exercise: use *Taylor-Young's quadratic approximation* near $0$: $$
\cos x= 1-\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2).$$

Second exercise: set $u=x+x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

with the rules of L'Hospitel we get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[6]{1+x+x^2}-1}{x}=\frac{1}{6}$$